# Merging two files by making a HDFS application that merges them into one file located in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

how the two different files may be indicated in the application, and then how to merge them

```
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;

public class Task1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String file_1 = args[0];
        Configuration config_1 = new Configuration();
        FileSystem into_fs = ???
        Path into_path = new Path(file_1)
```

Where is the file made, or how do I continue from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Filesystem.get(config_1)` will return a Filesystem object. From that, you need to specify String locations in the Path constructor, and create two of them. For example, you're already getting `args[0]`, so get another one for `args[1]`.

Your files need to exist on HDFS already, such as by `hadoop fs -put` commands.

Alternatively, just use `hadoop fs -getmerge` command, which is written in Java itself, and you could look at the source code, if you wanted

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, but I wanted to ask, how do I find the source code? My lecturer had skimmed over some of this information and I'm still too puzzled to follow, if it's alright for me to ask.

Comment: Source code is on Github, but you could also look at the Javadoc, such as the append method https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#append-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-